# Is there a way to prevent Data Explorer from ignoring whitespace in query parameters?

Tags: support, data-explorer, whitespace

I was thinking that a query to find posts with newlines followed by end-brackets might be useful for finding posts with code formatting issues-- for example, posts that look like this:

```
Here is what I have so far:

function foo() {
    return bar;
}
```

So I tried searching for posts with this in my query:

```
where body like '%\r\n}%'
```

However Data Explorer seems to not like that query (it eventually tells me something is wrong with the server). I also tried `'%\r}%'` (same result) and `'%\n}%'`. The query with `'%\n}%'` yielded results, but it isn't what I expected... The posts in the result set contain the literal `\n}`, not simply a line break in the post followed by a `}`.

I then tried:

```
where body like '%
}%'
```

This got me closer, but I was seeing posts that were properly formatted with `<code>`, `<pre>`, and/or spaces/tabs, so I tried to refine the query by adding:

```
and body not like '%<code>%'
and body not like '%<pre>%'
and body not like '%    %'
and body not like '%\t%'
```

That got rid of the posts with those tags, but judging by the result set, the query seems to match any number of optional spaces between the `\n` and the `}`, despite the first part of the WHERE clause and despite the part designed to filter out four consecutive spaces.

This means the query still matches posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118/how-to-set-up-a-css-switcher-in-asp-net/5160#5160) which are in fact properly formatted, in addition to the desired improperly formatted posts. I haven't yet confirmed whether the `'%\t%'` actually does anything.

Is there any way I can modify this query to search for what I want, or does Data Explorer always ignore whitespace like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the contents of the `Post` column, beware that non-formatted things like:

```
Here is what I have so far:

function foo() {
  return bar;
}
```

...are stored as:

```
<p>Here is what I have so far:</p>

<p>function foo() {
  return bar;
}</p>
```

(For which the code block would actually show on a single line in the browser.)

However, proper Markdown formatting of the code block would yield something like:

```
<pre><code>function foo() {
  return bar;
}</code></pre>
```

(For some reason, I see a lot of uppercase tags too.)

To tell those apart, a newline followed by a `}` is not what you're after. Instead, you'd need:

```sql
select top 10 Id as [Post Link], Body
from Posts
where Body like '%}</p>%'​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Or, to really limit to lines with a single curly bracket:

```sql
select top 10 Id as [Post Link], Body
from Posts
where Body like '%' + char(10) + '}</p>%'​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

The server being Windows, I assumed a newline would be `CRLF` (`char(13) + char(10)`), but testing <s>makes me think it's just `LF`</s> shows most posts use just `LF`. Maybe it's stored exactly as the browser sends it? (2,095 posts use `CRLF`; exactly one post did match `%CRLF}`, but searching for `%LF}` will find that one too of course, and you already fixed [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914/how-can-i-detect-if-a-browser-is-blocking-a-popup/2917#2917)...)

<sup>(The above, by the way, revealed many posts that you already fixed!)</sup>

Comment: Seems to do the trick. I never would have guessed that. Thanks!